# emoji picker flutter search function

Tags: flutter, dart, search, emoji

Has anyone used the emoji_picker_flutter package and used the search function provided? Trying to get it all to work and it's not working. Any help would be great, below is my code. I want the text input to be a search field instead and when clicking in the search field the emojis disappear until you search. I have been able to achieve that by assigning a set state and a bool there to display or not display the emojis, I just haven't been able to implement the search function with this package.

// Search for related emoticons based on keywords --- this is the given info to use to get the search to work ...

```
final filterEmojiEntities = await EmojiPickerUtils().searchEmoji("face");

import 'dart:io';

import 'package:emoji_picker_flutter/emoji_picker_flutter.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

/// Example for EmojiPickerFlutter
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
  bool emojiShowing = false;

  _onEmojiSelected(Emoji emoji) {
    _controller
      ..text += emoji.emoji
      ..selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(
          TextPosition(offset: _controller.text.length));
  }

  _onBackspacePressed() {
    _controller
      ..text = _controller.text.characters.skipLast(1).toString()
      ..selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(
          TextPosition(offset: _controller.text.length));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Emoji Picker Example App'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(child: Container()),
            Container(
                height: 66.0,
                color: Colors.blue,
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Material(
                      color: Colors.transparent,
                      child: IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            emojiShowing = !emojiShowing;
                          });
                        },
                        icon: const Icon(
                          Icons.emoji_emotions,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                        child: TextFormField(
                            onTap: () {
                              setState(
                                () {
                                  if (emojiShowing = true) {
                                    emojiShowing = false;
                                  } else {
                                    return null;
                                  }
                                },
                              );
                            },
                            controller: _controller,
                            style: const TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.black87),
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              hintText: 'Type a message',
                              filled: true,
                              fillColor: Colors.white,
                              contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                  left: 16.0,
                                  bottom: 8.0,
                                  top: 8.0,
                                  right: 16.0),
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                              ),
                            )),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Material(
                      color: Colors.transparent,
                      child: IconButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            // send message
                          },
                          icon: const Icon(
                            Icons.send,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          )),
                    )
                  ],
                )),
            Offstage(
              offstage: !emojiShowing,
              child: SizedBox(
                height: 250,
                child: EmojiPicker(
                    onEmojiSelected: (Category category, Emoji emoji) {
                      _onEmojiSelected(emoji);
                    },
                    onBackspacePressed: _onBackspacePressed,
                    config: Config(
                        columns: 7,
                        // Issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28894
                        emojiSizeMax: 32 * (Platform.isIOS ? 1.30 : 1.0),
                        verticalSpacing: 0,
                        horizontalSpacing: 0,
                        initCategory: Category.RECENT,
                        bgColor: const Color(0xFFF2F2F2),
                        indicatorColor: Colors.blue,
                        iconColor: Colors.grey,
                        iconColorSelected: Colors.blue,
                        progressIndicatorColor: Colors.blue,
                        backspaceColor: Colors.blue,
                        skinToneDialogBgColor: Colors.white,
                        skinToneIndicatorColor: Colors.grey,
                        enableSkinTones: true,
                        showRecentsTab: true,
                        recentsLimit: 28,
                        noRecentsText: 'No Recents',
                        noRecentsStyle: const TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20, color: Colors.black26),
                        tabIndicatorAnimDuration: kTabScrollDuration,
                        categoryIcons: const CategoryIcons(),
                        buttonMode: ButtonMode.MATERIAL)),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: do you want to search emoji by some text?

Comment: yes so if i enter smile it finds any emoji titled the same

Comment: ok, I am going to check it

Comment: I posted the answer, if you need any explanation just mention me

Comment: you checked or not?

Comment: @AliPunjabi it didnt work

Comment: Its working, just type "grinning face" and tap on button put a breakpoint on "filterEmojiEntities" and hover on it, you will see the list of four items of grinning face, you just need to use those list items in your widget wherever you want

Comment: I am going to edit my answer in which I will include screenshots of list data

Comment: now check the answer, I updated it

Answer (score -1):

```
 List? filterEmojiEntities;   
 Material(
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  child: IconButton(
                      onPressed: () async {
                        filterEmojiEntities = await EmojiPickerUtils()
                            .searchEmoji(_controller.text);
                       
                      }, 
                      icon: const Icon(
                        Icons.send,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      )),
                )
```

In the below screenshot, you can see the value of "_controller.text" is the same which I typed in textfield of simulator:
[image]

And here you can see the list of grinning face emojis:
[image]

Now you just need to use these list items where ever you want